# Copy a large file over an unreliable network

Tags: networking, sync

Basically I have an issue with employees using software such as solidworks and saving to their mapped drives (on a remote server) which the link sometimes fails and the network IT guys won't look at it.

Employees with the current problem are running:

- Windows 8.1 x64
- SolidWorks

The files are around 80MB or so.

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm thinking about making them save locally to a special directory such as C:\Foo\ and that location will be synced to the location on the mapped drive (If there is such software).

Comment: Create a split archive then extract the archive on the network share.

Comment: Do you have admin access? Would running a script on login/logout work in your scenario if you saved files to a local directory?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [file synchronization](http://superuser.com/a/405310/282305) software.

Comment: *"Unreliable network"* is redundant.  Ethernet and Internet Protocol are intrinsically unreliable.

Comment: Just to many options here - bitorrent sync, rsync, smb shares with a fault tolerant file copy software. What have you tried so far, and how do they fall short?\

Comment: Love bittorrent sync.

Comment: However, this is about a business environment, and it really is the local IT guys' responsibility to take care of this. Also, Solidworks has issues with this. We use it at my plant and even over a decently reliable network people are always getting connection-related errors from Solidworks.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to simply use the built-in `robocopy.exe` command with the `/z` option (copy files in restartable mode).

Combined with `/r` option (number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million), you might just be able to copy the file, without setting up sync or FTP servers.

The basic syntax would be something like:

```
robocopy <source dir> <destination dir> /z
```

I would advise you to run `robocopy /?` to see all the available options. It's a very flexible tool.